# What is the benefit of define constant by closure in Swift 3

Tags: swift

```
let a: UIView = {
    let a = UIView()
    a.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 20, height: 20)
    return a
}()
```

I saw a lot of people's Swift source code defining let as this way. I just curious what is the benefit of this way?

Comment: One advantage is that the code associated with this one property is nicely encapsulated in this closure. The advantage of this becomes more apparent when you have several properties, where putting all of this in a single `init` method can become unwieldy.

Comment: Hm ... why not use init(frame: CGRect) in this case? It is more clear and will simplify your code.

Comment: @user3441734 It is just an example. I saw many other places use this way to define a new constant.

Comment: @user3441734 as another (less contrived) example. I use this a lot for setting up labels etc... In the closure you can set up the font, textcolor, alignment, etc...

Comment: @Fogmeister yes, there are situations, where this approach could help. My own preference is to use a 'factory' in such a cases, which help me to make my code a little bit more readable. Try to imagine how hard is to find the final () if you need to initialise a lot of properties. Even worst, if you need to cascade in case one of them needs the same kind of initialization ...

Answer (score 2):

In this case, there is no benefit, but if the variable in question were a value type then the benefit would be that you could perform some mutating setup code and still get a constant out of it.

It also lets you hide temporary variables that were only needed to initialize the constant, since they'll only exist inside the closure's scope.